# Can I use a ternary opertator when there is a "return" from the conditions?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a procedure to go to another state and have this return. Previously I had coded it like this:

```
    if (self.word && row.wordId == self.word.wordId) {
        return this.$state.go('r.s.s.a.w.w.edit', {
            subjectId: self.sus.subject.id,
            wordId: row.wordId
        });
    } else {
        return this.$state.go('r.s.s.a.w.w', {
            subjectId: self.sus.subject.id,
            wordId: row.wordId
        });
    }
```

Now I am coding it like this:

```
   return self.word && row.wordId == self.word.wordId
        ? self.$state.go('r.s.s.a.w.w.edit', {
            subjectId: self.sus.subject.id,
            wordId: row.wordId
        })
        : self.$state.go('r.s.s.a.w.w', {
            subjectId: self.sus.subject.id,
            wordId: row.wordId
        });
    }
```

Can someone confirm if this is a valid way to do this or should I have returns before the self.$state.go ?

Comment: I'm of opinion that your previous code was easy to read and understand. Why the ternary then?

Comment: Surely you could have just tried it OP.

Comment: In most case, ternary are only used to assign two different values to the same var (exemple : if(boolean) ? true : false), especially for a 1 line condition. It's not very readable to convert a "complex" if condition (on many line) like you did. Prefer another method like Amadan suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your examples are identical, as far as I can see. However, I prefer the first one's readability.

In your specific case (not as a general solution), I'd probably write this:

```
var whereNext = self.word && row.wordId == self.word.wordId
  ? 'r.s.s.a.w.w.edit'
  : 'r.s.s.a.w.w';

return this.$state.go(whereNext, {
  subjectId: self.sus.subject.id,
  wordId: row.wordId
});
```

or even

```
var edit = self.word && row.wordId == self.word.wordId ? '.edit' : '';

return this.$state.go('r.s.s.a.w.w' + edit, {
  subjectId: self.sus.subject.id,
  wordId: row.wordId
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your're missing some brackets:

```
(self.word && row.wordId == self.word.wordId)
    ? return this.$state.go('r.s.s.a.w.w.edit', {
        subjectId: self.sus.subject.id,
        wordId: row.wordId
        })
    : return this.$state.go('r.s.s.a.w.w', {
        subjectId: self.sus.subject.id,
        wordId: row.wordId
    });
```

But I why would you do this? This make code less readable.
And you don't need it. You can remove "else":

```
if (self.word && row.wordId == self.word.wordId) {
    return this.$state.go('r.s.s.a.w.w.edit', {
        subjectId: self.sus.subject.id,
        wordId: row.wordId
    });
}
return this.$state.go('r.s.s.a.w.w', {
    subjectId: self.sus.subject.id,
    wordId: row.wordId
});
```

The Function returns in "if" so no else is needed.

Comment: The *"brackets"* are unnecessary but your second example is much more readable